# java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic11g

We are getting the following error in our clustered QA environment. We run Weblogic 10.3.3.0 on linux.

```
####<Mar 29, 2011 3:59:54 PM CDT> <Error> <Cluster> <app2.qa.server.com> <qa_app2j> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <1301432394933> <BEA-000126> <All session objects should be serializable to replicate. Check the objects in your session. Failed to replicate non-serializable object.
java.rmi.MarshalException: failed to marshal update(Lweblogic.cluster.replication.ROID;ILjava.io.Serializable;Ljava.lang.Object;); nested exception is:
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.tjf.admin.virtualFair.Job$1
at weblogic.rjvm.BasicOutboundRequest.marshalArgs(BasicOutboundRequest.java:92)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:221)
at weblogic.cluster.replication.ReplicationManager_1033_WLStub.update(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15419.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler$ReplicationServicesInvocationAction.run(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:184)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.invoke(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:154)
at $Proxy98.update(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.cluster.replication.ReplicationManager.updateSecondary(ReplicationManager.java:535)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionData.syncSession(ReplicatedSessionData.java:594)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionContext.sync(ReplicatedSessionContext.java:85)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2810)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2785)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl$1.run(ServletResponseImpl.java:1480)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.send(ServletResponseImpl.java:1474)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1455)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Here is the java file that is causing this:

```
package com.tjf.admin.virtualFair;

import com.tjf.TargetedJobFairsConstants;
import com.tjf.util.TargetedJobFairsToolBox;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Job implements Serializable {
protected int id;
protected String name;
protected String description;
protected int companyId;
protected String hash;

private static Logger logger = initializeLogger();

protected static Logger initializeLogger() {
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TargetedJobFairsConstants.TJF_LOG4J_NAME);
logger.info("logger initialized!");
return logger;
}
public Job(String name, String description, int companyId) {
this.name = name;
this.description = description;
this.companyId = companyId;
}

public Job(int id, String name, String description, int companyId) {
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.description = description;
this.companyId = companyId;
}

public Job(String name, String description) {
this.name = name;
this.description = description;
this.companyId = companyId;
}

public String getHash() {
if (id != -1 && name != null && !name.equals("")) {
return TargetedJobFairsToolBox.createHash(name, "" + id);
} else {
return null;
}
}

public int getCompanyId() {
return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
this.companyId = companyId;
}

public int getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public static boolean validateName(String name, StringBuffer message) {
if (name != null && !name.trim().equals("")) {
// check for duplicated Virtual Fair Company Name
return true;
} else {
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", Name ");
} else {
message.append(" Name ");
}
return false;
}
}

public static boolean validateDescription(String description, StringBuffer message) {
if (description != null && !description.trim().equals("")) {
return true;
} else {
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", Description ");
} else {
message.append(" Description ");
}
return false;
}
}

public static boolean validateCompanyIDString(String companyID, StringBuffer message) {
if (companyID != null && !companyID.trim().equals("")) {
return true;
} else {
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", unknown virtual fair error(32) ");
} else {
message.append(" unknown virtual fair error(32) ");
}
return false;
}
}

protected boolean insertJob(Connection tjfConn, StringBuffer message) {
PreparedStatement insertJobStmt = null;
String insertJobSQL = null;

try {
insertJobSQL = "insert into VIRTUAL_FAIR_JOB ( NAME, DESCRIPTION, COMPANY_ID ) " +
"values (?, ?, ?) ";

insertJobStmt = tjfConn.prepareStatement(insertJobSQL);
insertJobStmt.setString(1, this.name);
insertJobStmt.setString(2, this.description);
insertJobStmt.setInt(3, this.companyId);

insertJobStmt.executeUpdate();
message.append(" Job \"" + this.name + "\" was successfully created.");
return true;
} catch (Exception x) {
logger.error(x, x);
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", unknown virtual fair error(33) ");
} else {
message.append(" unknown virtual fair error(33) ");
}
return false;
}
}

protected boolean updateJob(Connection tjfConn, StringBuffer message) {
PreparedStatement insertJobStmt = null;
String insertJobSQL = null;

try {
insertJobSQL = "update VIRTUAL_FAIR_JOB set NAME = ?, DESCRIPTION = ? where" +
" COMPANY_ID = ? and ID = ?";

insertJobStmt = tjfConn.prepareStatement(insertJobSQL);
insertJobStmt.setString(1, this.name);
insertJobStmt.setString(2, this.description);
insertJobStmt.setInt(3, this.companyId);
insertJobStmt.setInt(4, this.id);

insertJobStmt.executeUpdate();
message.append(" Job \"" + this.name + "\" was successfully updated.");
return true;
} catch (Exception x) {
logger.error(x, x);
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", unknown virtual fair error(34) ");
} else {
message.append(" unknown virtual fair error(34) ");
}
return false;
}
}

public static boolean deleteJobByCompanyID(Connection tjfConn, int companyID, StringBuffer message) {
PreparedStatement deleteJobStmt = null;
String deleteJobSQL = null;

try {
deleteJobSQL = "delete from VIRTUAL_FAIR_JOB where " +
" COMPANY_ID = ? ";

deleteJobStmt = tjfConn.prepareStatement(deleteJobSQL);
deleteJobStmt.setInt(1, companyID);

deleteJobStmt.executeUpdate();
message.append(" Jobs were successfully deleted.");
return true;
} catch (Exception x) {
logger.error(x, x);
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", unknown virtual fair error(35) ");
} else {
message.append(" unknown virtual fair error(35) ");
}
return false;
}
}

public static boolean deleteJob(Connection tjfConn, int jobID, int companyID, StringBuffer message) {
PreparedStatement deleteJobStmt = null;
String deleteJobSQL = null;

try {
deleteJobSQL = "delete from VIRTUAL_FAIR_JOB where " +
" COMPANY_ID = ? and ID = ? ";

deleteJobStmt = tjfConn.prepareStatement(deleteJobSQL);
deleteJobStmt.setInt(1, companyID);
deleteJobStmt.setInt(2, jobID);

deleteJobStmt.executeUpdate();
message.append(" Job was successfully deleted.");
return true;
} catch (Exception x) {
logger.error(x, x);
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", unknown virtual fair error(36) ");
} else {
message.append(" unknown virtual fair error(36) ");
}
return false;
}
}

public static TreeMap<Job, Integer> getJobListforCompany(Connection tjfConn, int companyID, StringBuffer message) {
TreeMap<Job, Integer> jobsList = new TreeMap<Job, Integer>(new Comparator() {
public int compare(Object job, Object anotherJob) {
String name1 = ((Job) job).getName();
String name2 = ((Job) anotherJob).getName();
return name1.toLowerCase().compareTo(name2.toLowerCase());
}
});
PreparedStatement getJobListStmt = null;
String getJobListSQL = null;
ResultSet getJobListRset = null;
try {
getJobListSQL = "select ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, COMPANY_ID from VIRTUAL_FAIR_JOB where COMPANY_ID = ?";
getJobListStmt = tjfConn.prepareStatement(getJobListSQL);
getJobListStmt.setInt(1, companyID);
getJobListRset = getJobListStmt.executeQuery();

while (getJobListRset.next()) {
Job holdJob = new Job(getJobListRset.getInt(1),
getJobListRset.getString(2),
getJobListRset.getString(3),
getJobListRset.getInt(4));
jobsList.put(holdJob, holdJob.id);
}
return jobsList;
} catch (Exception x) {
logger.error(x, x);
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", unknown virtual fair error(37) ");
} else {
message.append(" unknown virtual fair error(37) ");
}
return null;
}
}

public static Job getJobByID(Connection tjfConn, int jobID, StringBuffer message) {

PreparedStatement getJobListStmt = null;
String getJobListSQL = null;
ResultSet getJobListRset = null;
try {
getJobListSQL = "select ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, COMPANY_ID from VIRTUAL_FAIR_JOB where ID = ?";
getJobListStmt = tjfConn.prepareStatement(getJobListSQL);
getJobListStmt.setInt(1, jobID);
getJobListRset = getJobListStmt.executeQuery();

Job holdJob = null;
if (getJobListRset.next()) {
holdJob = new Job(getJobListRset.getInt(1),
getJobListRset.getString(2),
getJobListRset.getString(3),
getJobListRset.getInt(4));
}
return holdJob;
} catch (Exception x) {
logger.error(x, x);
if (message.length() > 0) {
message.append(", unknown virtual fair error(38) ");
} else {
message.append(" unknown virtual fair error(38) ");
}
return null;
}
}
}
```

What might cause this?

Comment: Have this been working fine before? The only thing I can suggest is that your class contains something that is not serialisable - e.g DB connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the Comparator that's created on this line:

```
TreeMap<Job, Integer> jobsList = new TreeMap<Job, Integer>(new Comparator() {
```

At least, I think it is, because the `$1` in the stacktrace usually indicates an inner class, and that's the only inner class I can see. Plus, I believe creating it like that would make the TreeMap non-serializable (because it wants to serialize the comparator).

Instead of making it an anonymous class, declare it separately, and make it implement `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: +1 i was facing the same issue. You saved my Day :))))